# Reverse for 'teamEdit' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['teams/teamEdit/(?P<team_id>[0-9]+)/$']

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

Error : NoReverseMatch at /teams/teamEdit/12/

I'm a beginner in Django.
I'm trying to make a team app. But while Edit the team I'm facing some error.
Already I've tried some solutions from stackover flow but still showing the error.

Here Is The Code :

teamlist.html :

```
<a class="font-w500 align-items-center text-primary btn btn-link" href="{% url 'team:teamEdit' team.id %}">
 Edit
<i class="fa fa-edit ml-1 opacity-50 font-size-base text-primary"></i>
</a>
```

urls.py:

```
path('teamEdit/<int:team_id>/', teamEdit, name='teamEdit'),
```

views.py:

```
@login_required
def teamEdit(request, team_id):
    print(team_id)
    team = get_object_or_404(Team, pk=team_id, status=Team.ACTIVE, members__in=[request.user])
    print(team.title)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        title = request.POST.get('title')

        if title:
            team.title = title
            team.save()

            messages.info(request, 'The changes was saved')

            return redirect('team:teamList')
    else:
        return render(request, 'teamEdit.html', {'team': team})
```

teamEdit.html:

```
<h3 class="text-center">Eupdate Team</h3>
<form class="mb-5" method="post" action="{% url 'team:teamEdit' team.id %}">
{% csrf_token %}
 <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg form-control-alt"
     id="id_title" name="title" v-model="title" placeholder="Title">
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-success">Save</button>
 </div>
</form>
```

Error Traceback :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Django\TaskTracker\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Django\TaskTracker\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 179, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Django\TaskTracker\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py", line 21, in _wrapped_view
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Django\TaskTracker\venv\ttm\apps\team\views.py", line 68, in teamEdit
    return render(request, 'teamEdit.html', {'team': team})
  File "C:\Django\TaskTracker\venv\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py", line 19, in render
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
  File "C:\Django\TaskTracker\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py", line 62, in render_to_string
    return template.render(context, request)
  File "C:\Django\TaskTracker\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py", line 61, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "C:\Django\TaskTracker\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 170, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "C:\Django\TaskTracker\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 162, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Django\TaskTracker\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Django\TaskTracker\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Django\TaskTracker\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 150, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "C:\Django\TaskTracker\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 162, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Django\TaskTracker\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Django\TaskTracker\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Django\TaskTracker\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 62, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Django\TaskTracker\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Django\TaskTracker\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Django\TaskTracker\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py", line 446, in render
    url = reverse(view_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, current_app=current_app)
  File "C:\Django\TaskTracker\venv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\base.py", line 87, in reverse
    return iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs))
  File "C:\Django\TaskTracker\venv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 685, in _reverse_with_prefix
    raise NoReverseMatch(msg)

Exception Type: NoReverseMatch at /teams/teamEdit/12/
Exception Value: Reverse for 'teamEdit' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['teams/teamEdit/(?P<team_id>[0-9]+)/$']
```

Comment: Likely your template contains another `{% url 'team:teamEdit' %}`. You should also restart the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this

```
<h3 class="text-center">Eupdate Team</h3>
<form class="mb-5" method="post" action="{% url 'teamEdit' team_id=team.id %}">
{% csrf_token %}
 <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg form-control-alt"
     id="id_title" name="title" v-model="title" placeholder="Title">
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-success">Save</button>
 </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank You. I missed the parameter.